# Sync applications/settings between desktop and laptop

Tags: laptop, sync

Rather than having to set up all the applications I use on my laptop I'd rather be able to push some button that will get the laptop to install all the stuff that's installed on my desktop.

If it could do appearance settings and stuff too that'd be cool but it's not necessary.

Is this at all possible? Or will it be more trouble than it's worth and be better just to do manually?

I'm running 64 bit on my desktop and will probably run the 32 bit netbook remix on the laptop if that will further complicate things.

Comment: If all the applications you need are installed by the repositories you can just make a shell script that you can run on the laptop/desktop. If you have deb packets that is also possible with shellscript but I'm not sure if it really is worth the trouble. Also note that Ubuntu One syncs some stuff more like contacts and broadcast accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Oneconf](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneConf/) which uses Ubuntu One to sync your installed applications. Once installed (the package name is oneconf), it is used from Sowtware center's File menu.

Comment: Does it sync packages not represented in software center as apps and deps? What about side repos?

Comment: @Barafu: I guess it uses package lists and not application lists since the software center is just a gui to apt like synaptic. What do you mean by side repos? PPA? If yes, those pacgkages should be synced too. Maybe you should ask your own question if you want more details on Oneconf.

Answer (score 1):

To sync settings just sync all those invisible folders in you /home/username directory. You may use rsync or Ubuntu One. 
Syncing packages is a bit tricky, because if you just take a list of packages and install all of them, you will loose info on which are manual and whick are automatic. If this is not a problem, do `sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep '[[:space:]]install$='| awk '{print $1}' > installedpackages` to get a list and `cat installedpackages | xargs sudo apt-get --ignore-missing install` to install packages from the list.

Answer (score -2):

If you were on the same architecture (64-bit) It would be easy. If your laptop Is fairly modern, It will probably run 64-bit.

To copy your applications (that have been recently installed), press alt-F2 on the desktop and type in

```
  gksu nautilus
```

Now browse to the file system (/) and copy everything in the /var/cache/apt/archives folder to a thumb drive.

Now take that to the notebook (Only if it is the same architecture) Open synaptic PM (on the administration menu) and when it is done, Close the dialog, then go File -> Add downloaded packages. browse to your thumb drive and select the folder containing the cache. Once Synaptic has finished looking at the files, Click apply on the top menu. That will install all of the same applications as the desktop. As for installing them as you get them on your desktop, I believe there is a mod for software center that syncs the package list like Ubuntu One, and allows the other to mirror it. But right now I can't find it.